# Replace Space (%20) with dashes in url using .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am facing an issue in url re-writing in .htaccess. My url data coming from Database which include some spaces as well. I want to omit spaces from my url's and want to replace it with dashes.

currently what i am getting with my current .htacess ..

http://www.xyz.com/detail-10-Event%20Tickets.html

I want it to be replaced with

http://www.xyz.com/detail-43-61-Event-Tickets.html (This is what i want.)

Please find the code for .htaccess and suggest what changes should i made to solve this issue.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule uploadPRODUCT-(.*)-(.*)-(.*).html$ uploadPRODUCT.php?cid=$1&aid=$2&tid=$3

    RewriteRule ab-(.*)-(.*).html$ products.php?cid=$1&cname=$2 
    RewriteRule detail-(.*)-(.*)-(.*).html$ productDETAILS.php?cid=$1&aid=$2&pname=$3


    RewriteRule (.*)-(.*).html$ cms.php?name=$1&cmsid=$2



    errorDocument 404 http://www.xyz.com/notfound.php 
    errorDocument 500 http://www.xyz.com/500error.html

    RewriteCond %{http_host} ^xyz.com.com [NC]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L] 


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you create the URLs from database entries, I would replace the spaces at URL creation time. You can use [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for this

```
$url = str_replace(' ', '-', $db_column);
```